# Recursion and Dijkstra's Algorithm

Tags: c#, recursion, xna, dijkstra, maze

My recursive algorithm to navigate a maze takes way too long. Any suggestions on how to speed it up to be more efficient? Right now, it goes through every possible solution. When I tried to cut that down, it would then skip over many of the solutions, including the shortest. How do I cut down the number of solutions, or end some solutions early, while not skipping the shortest?

```
 private static void turnsforshortestmove(Vector2 location, int[,] board, int endrow, ref Boolean done, ref int[,] BOARDCHANGE, ref HashSet<int> h)
 //location is current location. board is the maze, endrow is the end y value to get to. it doesn't matter which x value, but as long as they get to the y value it's considered finishing.
 // done is a mistake, ignore it. BOARDCHANGE stores 
{
    //i need to compare all results for shortest
    //i need to cut off those that cant move
    if (location.Y == endrow)
    {
        h.Add(parseInt(board)); //counts how long the path is
        for (int r = 0; r < 19; r++)
            for (int c = 0; c < 19; c++)
                BOARDCHANGE[r, c] = board[r, c]; //sets the "real" board to have the path shown
    }
    else
    {

        int[,] boardCopy = new int[19, 19];
        for (int r = 0; r < 19; r++)
            for (int c = 0; c < 19; c++)
                boardCopy[r, c] = board[r, c];

        boardCopy[(int)location.X, (int)location.Y] = 8;


 //this part is saying if the square above isnt a wall, and two squares above isn't occupied, then do this function again

        if (boardCopy[(int)location.X, (int)location.Y - 1] == 1)
        {
            if (boardCopy[(int)location.X, (int)location.Y - 2] == 0)
            {
                turnsforshortestmove(new Vector2(location.X, location.Y - 2), boardCopy, endrow, ref done, ref BOARDCHANGE, ref h);
            }
        }    
        if (boardCopy[(int)location.X - 1, (int)location.Y] == 1)
        {
            if (boardCopy[(int)location.X - 2, (int)location.Y] == 0)
            {
                turnsforshortestmove(new Vector2(location.X - 2, location.Y), boardCopy, endrow, ref done, ref BOARDCHANGE, ref h);
            }
        }
        if (boardCopy[(int)location.X + 1, (int)location.Y] == 1)
        {
            if (boardCopy[(int)location.X + 2, (int)location.Y] == 0)
            {
                turnsforshortestmove(new Vector2(location.X + 2, location.Y), boardCopy, endrow, ref done, ref BOARDCHANGE, ref h);
            }
        }
        if (boardCopy[(int)location.X, (int)location.Y + 1] == 1)
        {
            if (boardCopy[(int)location.X, (int)location.Y + 2] == 0)
            {
                turnsforshortestmove(new Vector2(location.X, location.Y + 2), boardCopy, endrow, ref done, ref BOARDCHANGE, ref h);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

At the end, it looks through the Hashset to find the shortest path (number).

Comment: This isn't particularly clear.  Are you using Dijkstra's algorithm here?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I think his code is brute forcing the solution now.

Comment: This is solved by a basic breadth-first search. Start with a matrix with 0 at the initial position, max int everywhere else. Put the initial position into a queue. Then, keep going through the queue, and for each position in the queue, if a non-wall neighbour is > current + 1 in the matrix, set neighbour to current + 1 in the matrix and add its position to the queue. As soon as you get to the first position with y = desired y, you can backtrack from it to get a shortest path.

Comment: So the board will be passed in by reference so that each offshoot of the maze will be accessing the "master" board?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. There is no "passing", the algorithm I describe does not use recursion. It uses a matrix of integers, a queue of positions, and a while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Set up a matrix M with 0 at the initial location ("start") and max int everywhere else. Also create a queue of positions.

Then:

```
end = null
enqueue start
while queue is not empty
    p = dequeue
    if p.Y == desired_y
        end = p
        break
    for each neighbour of p // up, down, left, right
        if neighbour is not a wall and M[neighbour.X, neighbour.Y] > M[p.X, p.Y] + 1
            M[neighbour.X, neighbour.Y] = M[p.X, p.Y] + 1
            enqueue neighbour


if end == null
    return // no path exists

// now let's get the actual path, in reverse - from end to start
pos = end
path.add(pos)
while pos != start
    for each neighbour of pos
        if M[neighbour.X, neighbour.Y] == M[pos.X, pos.Y] - 1
            pos = neighbour
            path.add(pos)
            break


path.reverse // this is now your shortest path
```

Comment: What do you mean by queue of positions?

Comment: A queue data structure: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_(abstract_data_type) . There is one in C#, `Queue<T>`. By "position", I mean some kind of structure/class which holds the X and Y coordinates of a single location on the board. I assume that's your `Vector2`. So you would use a `Queue<Vector2>`.

Comment: Similar to stacks in Java?

Comment: No, a queue and a stack are opposite concepts. Stack is last-in-first-out, queue is first-in-first-out. With a stack, you add to and take from the same end. With a queue, you add to one end, and take from the other end.